# Can I use a photo printed on regular paper to purchase an Indian SIM card?

Tags: india, cellphones

I read on https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293860-i511-k10211967-Prepaid_Indian_Sim_card-India.html:

> For buying an Indian sim card, you would need a passport size photo, xerox copy of your visa and passport.

Can I use a photo printed on regular non-photo paper to purchase an Indian SIM card? Or does it have to be a photo printed on regular photo paper?

Comment: You will be hard pressed to find exact definition of "photo" for purpose of SIM purchase. From experience, they expect a photo on photo paper. YMMV if you submit photo on non-photo paper. E.g the executive may accept it but it may be rejected by back-end office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RedBaron said their comment, it depends on the person that sells you the SIM card. I was able to purchase SIM card at Airtel using a photo printed on paper (I had some paper copy of my passport and cut my photo from it). However, someone else at the Airtel who reviewed my application  wasn't happy about it but still left me off the hook (after picture of me on his phone).